# Lorentz Transformation Perpendicular Photons

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, inertial-frames, time-dilation

I'm trying to derive the Lorentz Transformation on my own but I'm stuck. This is probably something stupid, but I cannot figure out why I am not getting this right.

enter image description here

Here's what I did:

K and α are moving apart at velocity v. When α coincides with K, two photons are shot perpendicular to each other with A moving in the same direction as α. Fig 1 is from Ks perspective and Fig 2 is from α's.

α will just see photons A and B traveling straight to distance ct' = X' K, however, will see A moving forward while B moves at an angle moving as shown on Fig 1. Both moving distance ct = X.

I know that t ≠ t' and A ≠ A'. I am fairly certain that B = B' (though I'm not sure how one would know that). But if that's true, then B = √[(ct)^2 - (vt)^2] & B = B' then through some algebra we can get:

(ct')^2 = (ct)^2 - (vt)^2

then, (t')^2 = t^2 - (vX/c^2)

(t')^2 = (t + vt/c)(t - vX/c^2)

(t')^2 = [(1 + v/c) * (t - vX/c^2)^2] / (1 - v/c)

(t')^2 = [(1 + v/c)(t - vX/c^2)]^2 / (1 - v/c)(1 + v/c)

t' = (c + v)(t - vX/c^2) / √(c^2 - v^2)

which is close but has an extra v. I don't get why I keep getting the (c + v) when it should just be c.

Any help to show me where I'm going wrong would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

I was told not to substitute X/c = t in equation two. But if B happens as t as well as t' then why would that be wrong?[image]

Comment: Didn't you ask this last week?

Comment: Yeah, but no one will answer me :( I’ve gone over it but I don’t see what’s wrong. And I don’t know anyone personally that knows anything about it so I’m really stuck...

Comment: Please mark up your math with mathjax, and resize the gigantic image.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have a reference frame O (RF-O). It is often helpful to attach an infinite "number line ruler" (just like the real number line, with the origin of the reference frame at the zero mark of the ruler/scale) to RF-O and also affix/attach clocks at each point on the number line ruler. The ruler and the clocks are said to belong to the RF-O (Since they are attached to **O**). In favor of tidy statements, from now on, we'll call the clocks ($C_O$) and the ruler ($R_O$), whose names represent the RF to which they belong (in this case, it's RF-O). These clocks must be synchronized with respect to the frame to which they belong. In other words, the $C_O$ clocks must be synchronized with respect to RF-O. **[Refer 1.jpg]**
[image: 1.jpg]
          [1.jpg]

By synchronous, I mean that the clocks read the same reading as *observed* by a person who is at rest with respect to the reference frame to which the clocks belong. I say *observed*, because *observation* takes into account appropriate corrections for the measurement (such as the travel time of light signals). When a person merely *sees* the synchronized clocks, he will find that they show different times, due to the time it takes for the light signal from the clocks to reach his eyes.

Suppose you are at rest with respect to RF-K and you see another RF-$\alpha$ going to your right at velocity $v$, in front of you. RF-$\alpha$'s and RF-K's origins passed each other and the clocks attached to the zero marks of both the rulers read the same reading, namely zero. You're at rest with respect to RF-K, positioned at $x$ with respect to the $R_K$ ruler and the clock affixed at $x$ on the $R_K$ ruler reads $t$. At that instant, you look directly in front of you and note down the reading on the $R_\alpha$ ruler as well as the reading on the clock affixed to it (again, on the $R_\alpha$ ruler), at that location. These readings are $x'$ and $t'$ respectively. These are the readings you would see on the $R_\alpha$ scale if you jumped on that scale, at that instant.
Lorentz transformations describe the relationship between $(x,t)$ and $(x',t')$.

I'm explaining all this (in most probably a confusing manner) because you need to understand what Lorentz transformation is, in order to derive them. In your workings, you called $x$ as the position of the 'A' photon with respect to $R_K$. The $C_K$ clock at $x$ reads $t=x/c$. But, the $t'$ you wrote, is the reading of the clock affixed to the zero mark (origin of $\alpha$) of the $R_\alpha$ scale. That's not what we want. We want the reading on the clock affixed to the $R_\alpha$ scale, located just next to the 'A' photon. And that is not $t'$. [In fact, a person at rest in RF-K *observes* that the readings on the $C_\alpha$ clocks are all different (but they all run slow **[a]** by the same factor of $\gamma$). He also observes that the $R_\alpha$ scale has been contracted **[b]** by a factor of $\gamma$. $\gamma = {1 \over {\sqrt{1- {v^2 \over c^2}}}}$ ]

[image: 2.jpg]
[2.jpg]
Now, let's determine $t'$ **[Refer 2.jpg while reading this section]**. The following requires understanding of phenomena like relativity of simultaneity and time dilation (which you almost derived in your first two equations). The $C_\alpha$ clock affixed at the zero mark of the $R_\alpha$ scale reads $t/\gamma$ as *observed* by you (who is at rest wrt RF-K). Now, we would like to know what the $C_\alpha$ clock just next to the 'A' photon reads. What you *observe* is that, readings of two clocks separated by a distance $D$ as measured by the $R_\alpha$ ruler (NOT by the $R_K$ ruler) differs by $({{v D} \over c^2})$ **[c]**. The one on the right lags compared to the one on the left, when RF-$\alpha$ is moving to the right in front of you. Let's say the marking on the $R_\alpha$ scale just beside the 'A' photon is $x'$. We know that the scale has been contracted and hence, we get the following result. 
$$vt \text{(position of the origin of RF-$\alpha$ with respect to RF-K)} + {x' \over \gamma} \text{(contracted distance)} = x$$
$$ x' = \gamma(x-vt)$$
Now, we know that the clock at the zero mark of $R_\alpha$ scale and at the $x'$ mark of $R_\alpha$ scale are separated by a distance $x'$, as measured by the $R_\alpha$ scale. Therefore, if the clock at the zero mark of the $R_\alpha$ scale reads $(t/\gamma)$, then the clock at the $x'$ mark of the $R_\alpha$ scale (which is just next to the 'A' photon) reads
$$t' = {t \over \gamma} - {{x'v} \over c^2}$$
It is subtracted because the $C_\alpha$ clock affixed to $x'$ is to the right of the $C_\alpha$ clock at the zero mark of the $R_\alpha$ scale.
This simplifies (by substituting $x'$ from the previous equation) into
$$t' = \gamma(t - {{v x} \over c^2 })$$

I understand that this answer is complicated. But, I've tried to describe everything like which observer I'm talking about and which ruler/clock we're observing, in an effort to ensure no ambiguity. I would recommend Griffiths, David J. *Introduction to Electrodynamics* as a very good reference for Special Relativity.
I've used the facts (**[a],[b] and [c]**), as prerequisites to get the transformation equations.

Hope my answer has helped you in some way.